# What is the term for hosted JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find out what the terminology is that represents including JavaScript files that are hosted elsewhere. For example, there are payment gateway companies that will upon payment issue you a JavaScript file to include on a page of your application. This will render a payment UI on your site.

What is the name of something like that? Hosted JavaScript is the only thing I can come up with but I'm pretty sure that's not correct because I can't find many resources after doing a search on that.

Comment: I don't think there is such a term.

Comment: we usually just call them '3rd party libraries'

Comment: Thanks! Really can't understand the downvotes.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I surmise others downvoted because this question isn't exactly helpful to future users of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content Delivery Networks  quick overview https://w3guy.com/cdn-hosted-libraries/

Otherwise, shopping cart specific just needs to be compatible with your payment gateway and content management system.